# Can node-webkit or atom-shell take screenshot of entire desktop screen?

Tags: screenshot, node-webkit, electron

I want to take a screenshot of entire screen (<kbd>PrintScr</kbd>), not just browser window. Is this possible with either node-webkit or atom-shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom Shell can't do this natively, you'd have to write a native node module to do this, then include it in your project